# How Arrow function work inside constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am bit confuse about arrow function inside constructor.

As per my knowledge: **If we will use arrow function, the keyword this will not rebound to that actual function. it is inherited from the parent scope.**

let's take example:

```
var d = {
  b: 'b',
  x: () =>{
    console.log(this); // this will return Window Object.
 }
}
d.x();
```

it will print `Window` Object. that is fine.

But in constructor function

```
function A(){
  this.b ='b';
  this.x = () =>{
    console.log(this);
  }
}
var c = new A()
c.x();
```

**this print object `c`**. but according to me it should return Window Object. Why ?

Comment: Your *lexical scope* is already `A` (otherwise, `this.x = ...` wouldn't have worked in the first place).

Comment: it gets funny when doing: b=new A();c=new A();  b.x=c.x;

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor `this` refers to the object on construction. Why else could you do `this.b ='b';`?

Since an arrow-function simply captures the current context, it captures the object in the constructor.